# Rank a list based on different column

Tags: excel

I have two columns on Excel alike below (Num and Something)

```
Num  Something   Ranked 
1     0          2.31
2     2.31       2.35
3     5.36       5.36
4     2.35       0
```

What I want to do is, produce the 'Ranked' columns which would rank the 'Something' column based on the Num column (based on low to high number of Num column that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for this is the SMALL function, which gives you the nth smallest value from a list. Like so (assuming your columns there are A, B, and C, and your headers are on row 1), with the formula here in C2 and dragged down.

```
=SMALL(B:B, A2)
```

There is one complexity to deal with, however - you have a value of 0 that you appear to not want to include in your results. Now we will need to use an Array Formula to effectively create a new range which excludes those values. This can be done like so:

```
=SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$10<>0,$B$2:$B$10,""),A2)
```

Because this is an Array Formula, it will need to be confirmed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER. It essentially performs the IF statement for each cell in the noted range, and gives individual results - where B doesn't = 0, it shows the value in B on that cell. Where B = 0, it shows "" - which gets excluded from the SMALL function.

Note that Array Formulas work very slowly on entire columns, so you will need to specify how large your range in column B is here.

Comment: Thanks! That answers the question and an idea of how to do this in future. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @Shanan Glad I could help. If this solves your problem please mark the answer as 'accepted'.